# Issues while facing installing rmagic in Windows - rails 3 (bundle install)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get rmagick to work with rails 3 on windows.
I have manually installed the pre-compiled win32 version of rmagick and have this in my Gemfile:
gem "rmagick", "2.12.0"

But when I do bundle install, it tries to fetch it from the source (http://rubygems.org) instead of identifying that it is already installed on the system.
Here's what gem list rmagick shows on my system:

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rmagick (2.12.0 mswin32)

My ruby version is ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i386-mingw32]
Can anyone help me out on how to get this to work on windows?

Answer (score 2):

try to run:

```
set proxy=http://server:port

bundle install
```

Answer (score 2):

```
gem 'rmagick', "2.12.0", :platforms => :mswin, :require => false
```

However there's a bug in bundler and you will not be able to

```
require 'rmagick'
```

in your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run 'bundle install --local'.